# Як пояснити іноземцеві "м'який знак"?

Tags: фонетика, мʼякий-знак

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   [Is there a significant sound difference between Й and Ь?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/164)

Подруга вирішила вивчити українську мову. Цій новині я була безмежно рада. Почали ми з алфавіту... але Ь ("м'який знак")... Виявилось неможливим поянити цю літеру! Вона в алфавіті є, але ні звуку, ні транскрипції не має! 
Вона говорить англійською та трохи французькою мовами.

> В українськiй мовi буква Ь (м’який знак) позначає м’якiсть приголосних
>   звукiв.

Comment: мабуть має значення які мови вже знає ваша подруга

Comment: англійську та французьку

Comment: @Orti, коментарі для того пишуться, щоб спонукати до уточнення/покращення запитання. Це означає, що про англійську та французьку варто писати не у ще одному коментарі, а редагувати [edit] запитання і додати цю інформацію саме туди.

Answer (score 2):

Дещо сміховино, але пересічному сучасному українцю непросто пояснити *немʼякости* чи можливо і *мʼякости* приголосних перед буквою **і**.

Чому почав з букви **і**? Бо сучасна **і** включає **ролі *мʼякшення*** — цілковита і одна *суть букви **ь***. Зазначу, що подібний стан речей з **і** мають такі ӧтовані букви: **я, є, ю** — коли стоять одразу після приголосного; [драгоманівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) пропонувала замінити усіх йотованих на **ь** чи **й** + *голосна*, наразі таке тільки з **йо ьо**. В давнину і переважно для „західняків“ буква **ї** була теперішньою **і** — та що помʼякшує.

Отже наступне від [Олекси Синявського „Норми української літературної мови: § 10 І – Ї“](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9._%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8/%C2%A710_%D0%86_%E2%80%93_%D1%97) вказує на вимову пригосних з „чистою“ чи з тією самої *ролі* букви `і`.

> Тим, хто знають тільки сполучення **ні, ті, ді, лі** з м’якими приголосними і таким чином не вміють добре вимовляти характерних українських звукосполучень із твердими **н т д л** перед **і**, можна подати таку пораду, як навчитися поправно вимовляти тверді приголосні перед **і**: *м’які* **н т д л** (тобто в таких словах, як *приніс, дід, тіло, хліб*...) вимовляються так, що *кінчик язика спадає до спідніх ясен, а середня частина язика підіймається до піднебіння*; вимовляти ж *твердо* **н т д л** перед **і** (тобто в таких словах, як *ніч, худі, густі, плід*...) ми можемо тільки *упираючи кінчик язика в верхні ясна*, отже так, як і при вимові складів **ни, ти, ди, ли**. При *першій вимові* **н т д л** (м’яких) *середина язика випинається втору*, при другій (*твердих*) – *донизу*. Усе це добре видно в люстрі. Сполучення **ні, ті, ді, лі** з твердими приголосними (**л** тут буде “середнє” – див. § 9.) будуть достоту такі, як сполучення **н т д л** кінця слова перед **і** наступного, напр.: “*над Іваном*”, “*він і вона*” тощо (тут **ді, ні**, а не **ди, ни**!).

**Зауваження № 1:** про всяк зазначу, що **‚норми‘ тут „застаріли“** (основні причини: совітизація і мляві сучасні институти, переваги для ‚східняків‘ при правопису 1928 і так далі), але тут мовимо лиш про *твердости* — *мʼякости*;

**Зауваження № 2:** *(власні думки)* кінцеве положення язика дуже подібне до початкового положення язика звуку букви **й** — [**[j](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82)**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) (можливо, одна з причин, чому букву **j** південні словʼяни вживають одночас як щось **ь** чи **й** — в залежности положення), слово-перевірка: *каньйон*. Буде також доречним наголосити, що **й** має назву не тільки *йот*, а також *коротке **і*** — **[ĭ]** (котру наразі [переписують](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) як прасловʼянський **ь**) як коротке [**[i](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F)**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F).

Також анґломовна Вікі має статтю: [Palatalization](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) — ось і перепис **[ʲ]**, инколи також позначають [апострофом](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0). Ось [українська Вікі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F), але вона не дуже широка.

Comment: Мені подобається ця відповідь. Дає конкретну пораду щодо вимови (як язик вигинати, і з джерелами). Але одне але: Ви маєте розуміти, що «твердих звуків маё більшости мов» не відповідає дійсності. Бо мови, що не мають чіткої дихотомії тверде–м'яке (наприклад, англ.) зазвичай не мають такої твердої вимови приголосних, як мови з чіткою дихотомією (укр., а ще більше — рос.). Тобто англійців треба навчати вимові не лише м'який звуків, а й (і, можливо, в першу чергу?) твердих.

Comment: Бо англійські /d/, /t/, /n/ — це зовсім не тверді українські /d/, /t/, /n/. (А /l/ — окрема тема, бо /l/ самі українці часто вимовляють м'яко, в т.ч. полтавський діалект, який і покладено в основу літературної української мови, але чомусь правильною вважаються саме тверда вимова, як у росіян.)
Тому з часом все більше розумію, наскільки була недоречною [оця моя відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/179) — вона, можливо, могла би допомогти вимовляли м'які тому, хто вже вміє вимовляти тверді, але іноземець зазвичай не всіє ані ті, ані ті.